# Line bundles corresponding to divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$. Suppose $D_1$ and $D_2$ are divisors on $X$ such that $D_1\hookrightarrow D_2$, i.e. $D_1$ is a closed subscheme of $D_2$.

Then what is the relation between the line bundles $O_X(D_1)$ and $O_X(D_2)$. Can they be the same?

Edit - I am assuming that the $D_i$ are effective divisors. I am also interested in the case when the inclusion is not the identity morphism.

Comment: Of course they can be the same since you have not said that $D_1 \hookrightarrow D_2$ is not the identity morphism.

Comment: @MooS, Oh yes, I have not excluded that case. But I am interested in the non-trivial case. For example, if $D_1$ is an irreducible component of a reducible scheme $D_2$.

Comment: So $D_1$ and $D_2$ are effective divisors?

Comment: @MooS, Yes let me edit the question and add this detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The associated line bundles cannot be the same. If they were the same, the divisor $D_2-D_1$ would in particular have degree zero, but it certainly is an effective divisor of positive degree.

Comment: Sorry for what I am sure is a silly question. Why does it have positive degree. Also, is $O_X(D_1)$ a subsheaf of $O_X(D_2)$?

Comment: By your assumption on has $D_2 = \sum a_iE_i$ and $D_1 = \sum b_iE_i$ with $b_i \leq a_i$ (and for at least one $i$ the inequality is strict). Clearly the difference has positive degree. And yes, the first is a subsheaf of the second one. The first sheaf allows poles at $D_1$ while the second allows poles at $D_2$. So the second sheaf contains more functions, because more poles are allowed.

Comment: thanks for the great answer. I am curious though. Suppose $X$ is a smooth surface, Can we have a divisor $D_2$ ( a curve) which is thickened at just one point say. So if the reduced curve $D_1=(D_2)_{red}$, then it's not true that $D_2=a D_1$ for some $a$ right.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you are asking? If $D$ is reduced and irreducible, then of course $aD = a((aD)_{red})$.

Comment: I mean, can $D_2$ have embedded points? If it does is $D_2=a(D_2)_{red}$ for some a

Comment: A divisor of a smooth surface is a locally principal subscheme of a Cohen-Maucalay scheme, hence is Cohen-Macaulay again. In particular it fulfills Serres condition $S_1$ and has no embedded points.